# From where can I get hourly weather forecast data of Europe?

Tags: data-request, weather, europe

The [ECMWF](http://www.ecmwf.int/en/forecasts/datasets/public-wmo-and-acmad-datasets) website gives weather forecast data only twice a day (I'm only interested in temperature). Does anyone knows a reliable source for getting data hourly ? If `ECMWF` gives hourly data, then can anyone point me to that link ?

P.S. I don't want sources like `forecast.io`, `wunderground`.

Comment: can you cut short - you don't want to pay for data but sell derivative service? or what?

Comment: Do you want the forecast data or the actual historical measurements?

Comment: Forecast data. I think they have the historical data present.

Answer (score 1):

German weather survey DWD updates their data from Germany half-hourly: http://www.dwd.de/DE/leistungen/beobachtung/beobachtung.html

I think authorities from other European countries provide this kind of data as well. Espcially those with marine industries, e.g. fishing.

these windsurfing/kitesurfers forecasters update 4 times a day. I think they depend on publicly accessible products from DWD as well, cobined with their own digital elevation models:  http://www.muchoviento.net/index_en.html